# Keyframing Physics Animation

Tags: animation, game-engine, physics

I have a Rigid Body object that I want to be animated at a specific time. Can I animate it using the Blender Game engine? Also, is pressing <kbd>P</kbd> the only way to see it (can I see it using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensuring that blender is set to "Blender Game" mode, ensure that the "record animation" check box is ticked in the Game menu.
[image: How to record game animation to F-Curves]

Then hit 
<kbd>P</kbd> to start running the game (it'll probably run slower than normal). After the length of the animation you want to record has been recorded, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit playing the game. Press left/right on your keyboard, and you'll notice a key frame has been added to each object for every frame of the animation:

[image: A key frame is generated on every frame for each object]

(Also notice that if you play the animation using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> now, the physics will run as it does in the game engine as the position data has been applied to the objects using key frames).

If you want to delete part of this animation or shift all of the physics animation in time, enter the dope sheet window like so:

[image: How to enter the dope sheet to edit animation]

You can select key frames by pressing <kbd>B</kbd> and drawing a box around the key frames you want to select. When doing so, ensure that you select the key frames of the object that you want to edit the animation of, and not X,Y,Z location and rotation as that will distort the physics simulation. You can ensure you are not doing so by clicking on the arrows so that these options are not visible:

[image: How to ensure only the root transform of the object is being edited]

After you have selected the key frames of the object you want to edit, you can increase/decrease the speed of the animation using the <kbd>S</kbd> key and make the animation of that object occur later/earlier in time using the <kbd>G</kbd> key.

[image: Scaling the animation of the "Moving Object" object, making the animation slower]

You can also delete parts of the animation by box selecting the key frames you want to delete from the animation as outlined above, and pressing the <kbd>Del</kbd> key:

[image: Deleting key frames]

This will mean that the key frames of the object's animation you have deleted will not run (essentially cropping the start and end of the physics simulation if that is desired)